# Using addEventListener() in a for loop with various listeners

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add listeners to a number of buttons using a for loop. The appropriate listener for each button is indicated by the ID attribute of the button. Button IDs follow the form "button-[listenerName]". I get the list of all my button elements using `querySelectorAll()`, and then I iterate through that list, slicing out the name of each listener from the name of each button element. Then, I use the name of the listener with `addEventListener()` in an attempt to associate that button with its listener.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="button-listener1">Try 1</button>
<button id="button-listener2">Try 2</button>
<button id="button-listener3">Try 3</button>
<button id="button-listener4">Try 4</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var selector = "[id^=button]";
var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
for (var button of allButtons) {
  var listenerName = button.id.slice(button.id.lastIndexOf("-")+1);
  button.addEventListener("click", listenerName);
}

var listener1 = function() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHtml = "1";
}

var listener2 = function() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHtml = "2";
}

var listener3 = function() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHtml = "3";
}

var listener4 = function() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHtml = "4";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. What's up with that? Thank you.

Comment: What error your console shows?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You need to complete your question by adding details of what is not working.

Comment: well .. you are not adding a listener function, but a string .. What's up with that

Comment: Why not attach them to the same event listener. And when a button get clicked you can use `this.id` to know which button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 issues with your code:

1. In your for loop, you are essentially attaching strings as eventlisteners. You need to access your event listeners from the string you have.

Since you eventlisteners are declared in the global scopre, you can use `window` to access them:

```
button.addEventListener("click", window[listenerName]);
```

2. You are attaching the event listeners before declaring them. You need to declare `listener1` and so on before your for loop
3. `innerHtml` does not exist. The right syntax is `innerHTML`

Here is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="button-listener1">Try 1</button>
<button id="button-listener2">Try 2</button>
<button id="button-listener3">Try 3</button>
<button id="button-listener4">Try 4</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var listener1 = function() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "1";
}


var listener2 = function() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "2";
}

var listener3 = function() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "3";
}

var listener4 = function() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "4";
}

var selector = "[id^=button]";
var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
for (var button of allButtons) {
  var listenerName = button.id.slice(button.id.lastIndexOf("-")+1);
  button.addEventListener("click", window[listenerName]);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: upvoting this answer not because it is the most elegant or efficient solution, but because it approaches the problem from the question asker's perspective and empathizes with the asker's confusion

Comment: Thank you, this does what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

your line `button.addEventListener("click", listenerName);` tried to add a function called listenerName to the click event, and since listenerName is a variable and not a function, it doesn't work.

You could use an array of function to make it work instead.

```
var array_of_functions = [
    'listener1' : listener1,
    'listener2' : listener2,
    'listener3' : listener3,
    'listener4' : listener4
]
```

and then in your loop you could create the listener by giving the right function:

```
button.addEventListener("click", array_of_functions[listenerName]);
```

Also, make sure you create the function and the array before running the loop or they won't exist yet when the code runs.

Answer (score 1):

There's a slightly easier way to do this - just have *one* function that handles the event:

```
for (var button of allButtons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);
}

function handleClick() {
  var id = this.id.match(/button-listener(\d)/)[1];
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = id;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ry5akvuz/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can change your loop like this and your code will work

```
allButtons.forEach(function (button, i) {
    var listenerName = button.id.slice(button.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = i + 1;
  });
});
```